# Get height of table cell in based on content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, networking, cell

I want to get the height of a table cell using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I have two labels and one image in my prototype cell. Here's the storyboard:[image]

I'm having trouble using `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` because the size of my cells vary dramatically so I want to do this manually. I think it is best to size it according to the Title label or Author label shown in the image above since the image will be a static size.

There are a lot of Objective-C answers but I can't get it to work. Any thoughts on how to do this with Swift?

Answer (score 0):

I've made the same to help you. Please check it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 132.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
      cell.myTitle.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    }

    cell.myTitle.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.myAuthor.numberOfLines = 0

    return cell
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Hope it will help you to figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and easy try out this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }
```

And from story board set some properties through inspector such as

1. Keep number of lines as 0 for both label
2. Line Break as word wrap

And from constraint side

1. Don't give then height constraint
2. The most important thing i think you might have given would be
   bottom constraint to uiimageview with the cell so it would make
   problem.